# Intent to navigation drawer fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-pendingintent

I have set `android:launchmode="singletask"` for my current project.
So I'm suppose to redirect from ActivityB.FragmentA to ActivityA.FragmentB.

ActivityA.FragmentB is a fragment that is opened through navigation drawer.

So how do I intent to ActivityA.FragmentB?

Comment: in Oncreate Method of of your ActivityA just set the FragmentTransaciton commit for fragment B in the FragContainer after setContentView

Comment: problem is that I still have ActivityA.FragmentA. So when I redirect, I want to open a certain tab in the navigation drawer.

Comment: I used intent put extra but didn't have any effects.

Comment: so you are trying got say there is a TABVIew in your Activity A! right?

Comment: yeah. I wrote there fragment b is opened through navigation drawer

Comment: please put design view of your activity A and activityB so it would be easy to figure out the solution

Answer (score 1):

In intent call from ActivityB to ActivityA pass a boolean and on basis of it in ActivityA open the fragment ; pass false from elsewhere activityA is called.

Answer (score 1):

I used sharedpreferences to redirect it.

I set shared preferences when intent and get it while onResume().

SharedPreferences variable is deleted after that fragment is replaced.